# Reverse engineering on my simple C program

Tags: reverse-engineering, ollydbg

I would like to start learning reverse engineering.
So I decided to start simple.
I created this simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf ("Hello World!\n");
  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}
```

And I dissembled it in Ollydbg.
So I wanted to try and change the printf to "World Hello".
But I don't know what to do now.
Can you guide me, or at least tell me what I should theoretically do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this case you'd need to edit the character string that is passed to `printf`, but first we need to get its address. looking ad the code fro the call to `printf`, we will see something along the lines of this:

```
PUSH mymodule.1234567
CALL printf
ADD ESP,4
```

so if we go to the address `0x1234567`, via <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd>, we would see:

```
01234567   48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 57 6F 72 6C 64 0A 00 00 00 00  Hello World.....
```

so now you can edit that string to whatever you want, so long as you don't overflow the space available and you keep the null terminator.

Saving the changes depends on how you loaded the binary (either by attaching or just cold viewing), the easiest way is via cold viewing (using olly purely as a disassembler/assembler). Its access via `view -> file` then right-clicking and choosing `disassemble` from the context menu. In this mode saving is done by right clicking and selecting `save file` from the context menu .

In debugger mode (aka when you attach), saving is done using right-click, and selecting one of the options from the `copy to executable` context menu option.

---

### Update

If you are debugging GCC generated code, it generally avoids generating `PUSH`'s and favours putting the variables directly into the stack, using `MOV [ESP+c],c/r/m`. Compiling your example with GCC, you'd see code similar to (for `main`):

```
00401AFC     /$  PUSH EBP
00401AFD     |.  MOV EBP,ESP
00401AFF     |.  AND ESP,FFFFFFF0
00401B02     |.  SUB ESP,10
00401B05     |.  CALL GCCOllyT.0040182C
00401B0A     |.  MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],GCCOllyT.00403024   ; ||ASCII "Hello World!"
00401B11     |.  CALL <JMP.&msvcrt.puts>                    ; |\puts
00401B16     |.  MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],GCCOllyT.00403031   ; |ASCII "PAUSE"
00401B1D     |.  CALL <JMP.&msvcrt.system>                  ; \system
00401B22     |.  XOR EAX,EAX
00401B24     |.  LEAVE
00401B25     \.  RETN
```

Its important here to notice that GCC optimized the call to `printf` into a call to `puts`. In a case like this where you know the string you are looking for, you can use olly in debugger mode, right-click and select `search for -> all referenced text strings`, then simple select your desired string from the list to find the code using it, or follow its address to find its `.data` section entry so you can alter it. A longer way to find it is to use the binary search available from the right-click context menu, but this generally is a waste for text strings.

And to cover all bases, lets assume we needed to get to the code from the entry point.
If we where to navigate to the code from the module entry point, we would follow the chain like so:

```
GCCOllyT.<ModuleEntryPoint> 0> $ >PUSH EBP
0040126D                       . >MOV EBP,ESP
0040126F                       . >SUB ESP,18
00401272                       . >MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],1
00401279                       . >CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&msvcrt.__set_app_type>;  msvcrt.__set_app_type
0040127F                       . >CALL GCCOllyT.00401000
00401284                       . >PUSH EBP
00401285                       . >MOV EBP,ESP
00401287                       . >SUB ESP,18
0040128A                       . >MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],2
00401291                       . >CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&msvcrt.__set_app_type>;  msvcrt.__set_app_type
00401297                       . >CALL GCCOllyT.00401000
0040129C                       $ >PUSH EBP
0040129D                       . >MOV EBP,ESP
0040129F                       . >SUB ESP,8
004012A2                       . >MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[<&msvcrt.atexit>]
004012A7                       . >LEAVE
004012A8                       . >JMP EAX
```

from here we see the only viable call as `GCCOllyT.00401000`, following that, we end up here (this is the GCC `mainCRTstartup`):

```
00401000   /$ >PUSH EBP
00401001   |. >MOV EBP,ESP
00401003   |. >PUSH EBX
00401004   |. >SUB ESP,34
00401007   |. >MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[403038]
0040100C   |. >TEST EAX,EAX
0040100E   |. >JE SHORT GCCOllyT.0040102C
00401010   |. >MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+8],0
00401018   |. >MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+4],2
00401020   |. >MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],0
00401027   |. >CALL EAX
00401029   |. >SUB ESP,0C
0040102C   |> >MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],GCCOllyT.00401110           ; |
00401033   |. >CALL <JMP.&KERNEL32.SetUnhandledExceptionFilter>   ; \SetUnhandledExceptionFilter
00401038   |. >PUSH EAX
00401039   |. >CALL GCCOllyT.004013CC
0040103E   |. >CALL GCCOllyT.004014AC
00401043   |. >MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-10],0
0040104A   |. >LEA EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-10]
0040104D   |. >MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+10],EAX
00401051   |. >MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[402000]
00401056   |. >MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+C],EAX
0040105A   |. >LEA EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-C]
0040105D   |. >MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+8],EAX
00401061   |. >MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+4],GCCOllyT.00404004
00401069   |. >MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],GCCOllyT.00404000
00401070   |. >CALL <JMP.&msvcrt.__getmainargs>
00401075   |. >MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[404018]
0040107A   |. >TEST EAX,EAX
0040107C   |. >JNZ SHORT GCCOllyT.004010C8
0040107E   |> >CALL <JMP.&msvcrt.__p__fmode>
00401083   |. >MOV EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[402004]
00401089   |. >MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EAX],EDX
0040108B   |. >CALL GCCOllyT.004015E4
00401090   |. >AND ESP,FFFFFFF0
00401093   |. >CALL GCCOllyT.0040182C
00401098   |. >CALL <JMP.&msvcrt.__p__environ>
0040109D   |. >MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EAX]
0040109F   |. >MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+8],EAX
004010A3   |. >MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[404004]
004010A8   |. >MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+4],EAX
004010AC   |. >MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[404000]
004010B1   |. >MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],EAX
004010B4   |. >CALL GCCOllyT.00401AFC
004010B9   |. >MOV EBX,EAX                                        ; |
004010BB   |. >CALL <JMP.&msvcrt._cexit>                          ; |[msvcrt._cexit
004010C0   |. >MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],EBX                         ; |
004010C3   |. >CALL <JMP.&KERNEL32.ExitProcess>                   ; \ExitProcess
004010C8   |> >MOV DWORD PTR DS:[402004],EAX                      ; |||
004010CD   |. >MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+4],EAX                       ; |||
004010D1   |. >MOV EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[<&msvcrt._iob>]              ; |||msvcrt._iob
004010D7   |. >MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EBX+10]                      ; |||
004010DA   |. >MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],EAX                         ; |||
004010DD   |. >CALL <JMP.&msvcrt._setmode>                        ; ||\_setmode
004010E2   |. >MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[404018]                      ; ||
004010E7   |. >MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+4],EAX                       ; ||
004010EB   |. >MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EBX+30]                      ; ||
004010EE   |. >MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],EAX                         ; ||
004010F1   |. >CALL <JMP.&msvcrt._setmode>                        ; |\_setmode
004010F6   |. >MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[404018]                      ; |
004010FB   |. >MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+4],EAX                       ; |
004010FF   |. >MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EBX+50]                      ; |
00401102   |. >MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],EAX                         ; |
00401105   |. >CALL <JMP.&msvcrt._setmode>                        ; \_setmode
0040110A   \.^>JMP GCCOllyT.0040107E
```

Now we know the signature for the call to `main` takes 3 args, we also know it will be called *before* app cleanup and exit, thus we get `GCCOllyT.00401AFC`. As you can see, it pays heavily to have symbols enabled, this can be done from the disassembly section of the debugging options menu.

Comment: First of all, thank you. Is this what I need to find ? (http://postimage.org/image/v8e51e7m9/) I can't seem to find a matching expression to what you said. Plus, how can I find (easily) the "PUSH mymodule.123..."?

Comment: @agam360: yours is a little different as it looks like your using mingw(gcc) and ollydbg 2. lemme update for that case.

Comment: Thanks for the update, sorry if my question Is a bit ignorant, but I can't seem to find that "...GCCOllyT.00403024" Line, all I have is this: "MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],OFFSET 00403000 //ASCII "Hello World!" ", do you know what are our differences? plus where I can find the call to the stored characters?(Where can I actually change the string?) Thanks in advance.

Comment: @agam360: your addresses won't match mine, as the base loading address will change, but in your case `00403000` is the address to goto to edit the text string